# Symfony2. Добавление js события для тега input

Tags: symfony, php, html, javascript

Для построения формы использую FormBuilder:

```
$builder->add('cardId', 'number', array('label' => 'card.id');
```

А в шаблоне вывожу {{ form.widget }}

Как навесить на тег какое-либо событие? (конкретно требуется onKeyPress)

Answer (score 1):

При чем тут php? Подключите к странице Ваш скрипт, где при окончании загрузки выполните:

```
$('selector').keypress(function(e){
//Your code here
});
```

Требуется `jQuery`.

Comment: Спасибо, но если бы мне хотелось использовать jQuery, я бы не спрашивала :)

Comment: А окромя jQuery нету вариантов отследить загрузку страницы и навешать обработчик? О_О
document.onload = function(){
var elem = document.getElementById('');
elem.onkeypress = function(e) { /**/ }
}